# Vue and Jexcel events and computed fields

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am using the vue wrapper for jexcel and am attempting to trigger the undo function from the toolbar computed field. I cannot seem to access the instance of the spreadsheet. it throws a this.undo is undefined error

```html
<template lang="html">   
  <div class="wrapper-jexcel">
    <button class="" @click="getData(jExcelObj)">Data</button> 
     <button class="" @click="jExcelObj.undo()">Undo</button> 
    <input
      type="button"
      value="Add new row"
      @click="jExcelObj.insertRow()"
    />
    <div id="spreadsheet" ref="spreadsheet"></div>
  </div>
</template>
```

```js
import jexcelStyle from "jexcel/dist/jexcel.css"; // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars
import jexcel from "jexcel"; // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars
import db from '@/firebase/init'
import firebase from 'firebase'

export default {
  name: "workbook",
  data() {
    return {
      workbookid: this.$route.params.workbookid,
      myCars: [],
      columns: [
        { type: "text", title: "Car", width: "120px" },
        {
          type: "dropdown",
          title: "Make",
          width: "250px",
          source: ["Alfa Romeo", "Audi", "BMW", "Honda", "Porshe"]
        },
        { type: "calendar", title: "Available", width: "250px" },
        { type: "image", title: "Photo", width: "120px" },
        { type: "checkbox", title: "Stock", width: "80px" },
        {
          type: "numeric",
          title: "Price",
          width: "120px",
          mask: "$ #.##,00",
          decimal: ","
        },
        { type: "color", width: "100px", render: "square" }
      ]
    };
  },created() {
    this.getworkbook()
  },

  methods: {
    onchange(){
      console.log('change');
    },
    insertRowc() {
      console.log(this);
      // this.spreadsheet.insertRow();
    },
    undo(){
      console.log('test');
        jExcelObj.undo();
    },

 getData(payload) { 
   console.log(this.myCars);
   console.log(payload);
  // this.myCars = payload.data
 }
  },
  computed: {
    jExcelOptions() {
      var self = this;
      return {
        data: this.myCars,
        columns: this.columns,
        search: true,
        //fullscreen: true,
        minDimensions: [20, 40],
        defaultColWidth: 100,
        allowComments: true,
        toolbar: [

              { type:'i', content:'undo', onclick:function() { return jExcelObj.undo(); } },
        { type:'i', content:'redo', onclick:function() { this.redo(); } },
        { type:'i', content:'save', onclick:function () { test.download(); } },
        { type:'select', k:'font-family', v:['Arial','Verdana'] },
        { type:'select', k:'font-size', v:['9px','10px','11px','12px','13px','14px','15px','16px','17px','18px','19px','20px'] },
        { type:'i', content:'format_align_left', k:'text-align', v:'left' },
        { type:'i', content:'format_align_center', k:'text-align', v:'center' },
        { type:'i', content:'format_align_right', k:'text-align', v:'right' },
        { type:'i', content:'format_bold', k:'font-weight', v:'bold' },
        { type:'color', content:'format_color_text', k:'color' },
        { type:'color', content:'format_color_fill', k:'background-color' },
        ]
      };
    }
  },
  mounted: function() {
    //console.log(this.jExcelOptions);
    //console.log(this.$refs["spreadsheet"]);
    const jExcelObj = jexcel(this.$refs["spreadsheet"], this.jExcelOptions);
    // Object.assign(this, jExcelObj); // pollutes component instance
    Object.assign(this, { jExcelObj }); // tucks all methods under jExcelObj object in component instance
    // console.log(this.jExcelObj);
  }
};
```

should i be passing the instance into the computed method? I am struggling to understand how to manage instances of a wrapper plugin and accessing the methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the instance using that:

```
var yourTableInstance = document.getElementById('spreadsheet').jexcel;

yourTableInstance.undo();
yourTableInstance.getData();
```

Comment: is there any way I can assign/update the source in the column (of type: dropdown) dynamically after getting data from API? @Paul Hodel.

Comment: Yes, you can do:

    yourTableInstance.options.columns[colNumber] = { type:'dropdown', source:['','',''] }

Answer (score 0):

```js
mounted: function() {
  let spreadsheet = jspreadsheet(this.$el, options);
  Object.assign(this, spreadsheet);
}
```

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/32682712)